# PHP preg_replace Help

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need help replacing a link like google.com into http://www.google.com

```
$url = preg_replace("/([^\w\/])(www\.[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z0-9\-]+)/i", "$1http://$2",$url);
$output = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($url));
```

I'm using an iframe like:

```
<iframe src='$url'></iframe>
```

However, if the src="google.com" instead of "http://google.com" it will not work. So, how can I transform google.com into http://www.google.com?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non regex hack way to do it.

```
$url = 'google.com';
function addHTTP($url) {
 return 'http://'.str_replace('http://','',$url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "www.google.com";
if(!preg_match("/^https/i",$url))
    $url = "http://$url";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do this, but this will work:

```
if(!preg_match("#^http:\/\/#", $url)) {
         $url = "http://".$url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://' . $url;
```

the simpliest way possible :o

Answer (score 0):

How about checking if `http://` is on the beginning of it and if not tag it on? Like so:

```
$url = 'google.com';
if (!preg_match('#^http://#', $url)) {
  $url = 'http://'.$url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's one that uses just preg_replace by taking advantage of a negative lookahead. However, I agree with the other solutions here, that it is probably best to just to a preg_match and then a string concatenation.

```
$url = preg_replace('#^(?!https?://)#', 'http://', $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make your RegEx match google.com e.a., all you have to do is make www. optional. Please note that this may introduce other problems, such as `end.begin` being recognized as an URL.

```
/([^\w\/])((www\.)?[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z0-9\-]+)/i
```